# Checking whether a large CSV file (1m rows) has the same data as a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to find a way to efficiently compare a CSV file content with a MySQL database (Over 1 Million rows to compare), I've done something similiar before just placing all the rows into an array but that will work for a small number of rows because of memory overloading.

My question is, is there a recommendable way to doing that? Any libraries or something that could help?

I would appretiate your answers.

Comment: By "compare" are you testing all fields or just particular fields? Is this a background task or is a user waiting while it happens? If you could provide more detail on what you're actually trying to do (eg, reason for the compare) someone may be able to suggest a different way to approach the problem.

Comment: If you have that many rows, how about loading the CSV into a temp table and doing your compare against that?

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure that the data in my database (previously imported) matches with the data that the CSV file has and print out (for myself) the number of rows that matches and the number of rows that doesn't match.

Comment: Presumably you mean CSV (comma separated value) rather than CVS (concurrent versions system)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming this is a sanity check and you're aiming to have 0 differences, how about dumping out the database as a CSV file of the same format and then using command line tools ([`diff`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff) or [`cmp`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cmp)) to check that they match?

You'd need to make sure your CSV dump is ordered & formatted the same as the original file of course.

Comment: The problem with that is that I won't know where the error is, what's the difference or in which rows the problem is.

Comment: Why wouldn't you? Have you ever used a [`diff` tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)?

Comment: True, it would print out differences. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Besides @therefromhere's excellent answer, you could also calculate a hash, both in MySQL and in the original file and then compare the two.

Comment: Nice answer too, but can't easily locate the error if there's one

Comment: No, unless you do a hash per row.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it myself, but MySQL has a CSV table type. You may be able to have MySQL read the file directly as if it was just another database table. You would probably need to create an empty table first that matches the CSV file you have, just so the .frm file is created in the data directory. Then you can replace the empty .csv file in the data directory with your CSV file. You may need to run a repair table since you didn't do an import.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/csv-storage-engine.html